# AWS Glue DynamicDataFrame reports zero records for RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

We configured AWS Glue to execute ETL jobs from RDS (postgres instance) to AWS Redshift. Both Redshift and RDS are deployed to private VPCs. Initial script was generated by Glue console and jobs executed always succeed. But somehow dynamic frame created always returns zero records, although they are present in source table.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database", table_name = "table", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
print "Count: ", datasource0.count()
```

What can be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Did you enable bookmarking on the jobs?

Comment: Yes, checked both ways - with and without bookmarking